# How to automatically get from daily e-mail attachment to script-processed file?

Tags: email, scripting, email-attachments, email-processing

**Background:** Every work day I get an e-mail from a vendor who sends me a CSV file as an attachment. The CSV file needs to be converted into HTML and I already have a script that does that.

The problem is, I have to manually open my e-mail, save the attachment to my hard drive and then run the script against the saved attachment. I would like to do this all automatically because it is getting tedious.

I always have to save the e-mail attachment to a known file path on some file system somewhere and then run a script against that known file path to convert it to a different format for reporting purposes.

**Question:** Assuming I can forward the e-mail and attachment anywhere, how can I automate this process? Is there some kind of SMTP to SCP gateway? How does one automatically go about converting e-mail attachments into files with known paths on a filesystem so they can be processed via script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to two articles I found, this can be done in VBScript uncer certain conditions.  Rather than go in depths here, I'll give you the articles:

http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/emailObject_saveAttachments.asp

http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.exchange.development/topic32825.aspx